# If user login in with ELGG

Tags: php, elgg

I want to create new page under elgg script, but this page should be private of users.
So I tried this code but nothing appear on page:

```html
if (elgg_is_logged_in()) {

    echo "Welcome";
    }
```

I already read all tutorials on this link: http://learn.elgg.org/en/2.0/guides/authentication.html
but I don't know why it's blank.

Comment: You provide way to little info. How do you create the page? Does it work without the if condition?

Comment: It should work . if you had put it at correct place.  just add else block and echo something.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`elgg_gatekeeper()`](http://learn.elgg.org/en/1.10/guides/gatekeeper.html).